# Как распределяются изображения в ресурсах Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Собственно, прочитал и сделал набор папок следующей структуры:

1. drawable-hdpi
2. drawable-ldpi
3. drawable-mdpi
4. drawable-tvdpi
5. drawable-xhdpi
6. drawable-xxhdpi
7. drawable-xxxhdpi

И в них распределил изображения по разрешениям. Далее, смотрю в дизайнере. В самой свежей Android Studio доступны следующие разрешения (для планшетов и смартфонов, остальное не важно): tvdpi, xhdpi и список под разную плотность (440dpi и тд). Я смотрю планшеты с xhdpi и tvdpi - меня устраивает отображение изображения. Далее я смотрю все смартфоны с *dpi - и вот тут начинаются проблемы. Дело в том, что все устройства берут изображения из xhdpi.

Почему так происходит и в какую папку надо положить на самом деле? Ниже приведен скриншот нужных девайсов (смотрю в дизайнере, в эмуляторах / реальных девайсах тоже самое). Какая папка внутри *drawable* соответствует всем разрешениям из категории *Phone*?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: @DiD спасибо, то, что надо :)